# How to find out common data points from two lists containing three dimensional data?

Tags: python, set

I have two lists containing three dimensional x, y and z coordinates, say cap coordinates and whole coordinates. I need to find out the uncommon data points which exists in the whole coordinates but not in cap coordinates. I made two arrays from the two lists, call them as sets and then consider
set (core)= set(whole)-set(cap)

`

```
with open('whole.txt') as c:
    wholestr=c.readlines()
    whole_str=(np.loadtxt(wholestr))
    whole=np.array(whole_str)
with open('cap.txt') as d:
    capstr=d.readlines()
    cap_str=(np.loadtxt(capstr))
    cap=np.array(cap_str)

# calculation of core coordinates #
core=list((set(wholestr)-set(capstr)))
#core=list((set(wholestr).symmetric_difference(set(capstr))))
with open('core.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in range(len(core)):
        f.write(core[x])
```

`
I tried the difference method, also again with symmetric_differece.Since both sets have equal no of elements, it results null value of core. What to do?

Comment: Can you provide example data ? What is the expected output ?